# Why when initializing byte array with the same value gives different value/bytes?

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I have the following code :

```
byte[] data = "String".getBytes();
System.out.println("data: " + data);
```

and on some runs I get different output values, e.g.

```
data: [B@4769baee
data: [B@308c3eb8
data: [B@7b3a4cdc
```

Why this is happening ?

Comment: that's not the actual value, it's the objects 'name'

Comment: When you print out a byte array like that, you actually call the `toString()` method of array. Unfortunately, that does not print the contents of the array, but the hashcode of the instance http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29 Use `Arrays.toString(data)` instead.